# React js Compiled with warnings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-scripts

I am junior backend developer but I use the react library in my clone projects

After updating the react script, I started getting a lot of errors in my project. I solved some of them, how can I solve them or ignore them

node -v v14.17.0
[image]

[image]

Comment: When it says missing dependency, add them to your second parameter of `useEffect` like `[getAction, params.id, allComments]`. Can you show your `Line 55`?

Comment: The errors are very self-explanatory. Add properties to your useEffect dependency array, and make sure your `filter` actually returns something.

Comment: @GeekyQuentin Which error line should I show?

Comment: Not the error line, show Line 55 in your code

Comment: @GeekyQuentin I added image

Comment: Yes, so the problem is the code inside the `else` statement might not be read, and hence it might not return anything, add a default return value that gets returned if none of the conditions satisfy

Comment: @GeekyQuentin I understand very well, thank you. So what is causing this error?   React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency:

Comment: also why am i getting these errors when i update the package

Comment: Can you add your `useEffect()` code and for what you are sorting `CommentLists` for?

Comment: [Please post code as text, not images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: @GeekyQuentin  I made a youtube comment system. I have listed the comments. I wrote a function like this to edit the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)'s second parameter is a dependency array. When one or more dependencies have changed from the last render, the effect is recalled. You're getting this error because you haven't included all necessary variables or functions in your dependency array, which can lead to stale data and unexpected behavior.

For example, your hook in `PostBody.jsx` is missing the dependency `params.id`. The fix is to simply add the value to the dependency array:

```
// PostBody.jsx
useEffect(() =>
{
    // Your code here
}, [params.id, ...yourOtherDependencies]) // Add params.id to your dependency array
```

Do the same for your hooks that are missing `getAction` and `allComments`.

Regarding the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) error, you're not returning a value in the first condition:

```
const newCommentArr = CommentLists.filter((comment, index) =>
{
    if (newComment._id === comment._id)
    {
        indexValue = index
        // You need to return a value!
    }
    else
    {
        return newComment._id !== comment._id
    }
})
```

The value you return depends on what you're using this for. You may be able to just change your code to:

```
const newCommentArr = CommentLists.filter((comment) => newComment._id === comment._id)
```

or

```
const newCommentArr = CommentLists.filter((comment) => newComment._id !== comment._id)
```

based on what you're using this for.

Comment: ` useEffect(() => {
   
    fetchSinglePost(params.id)


}, [params.id])` this solved the error but  ` useEffect(() => {
   
    dispatch(fetchSinglePost(params.id))


}, [dispatch])`  why is this wrong

Comment: and `useEffect(() => {
  
    allComments()
    
    }, [])`  What do you think I should give here, this way the error is really solved

Comment: Just add the function `allComments` to the dependency array. `useEffect(() => { allComments() }, [allComments])`

Comment: ı am sory  I did but it gives a new error   The 'allComments' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 122) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the definition of 'allComments' in its own useCallback() Hook  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps  how to solve (:

Comment: https://typeofnan.dev/fix-function-makes-the-dependencies-of-useEffect-hook-change-on-every-render-warning-in-react/  it's explained here but I didn't know what to add to the hook

Comment: If that's the case, you need to define and call the function within `useEffect`, use `useCallback`, or change your architecture. This is the subject of another question. If this answer helped solve some issues, consider accepting it and starting a new question

Comment: i finally figured it out   ı write params.id,CommentLists and finish  (: I hope it's true

Answer (score 0):

To get help to know your linting error, you could setup [ESLint](https://medium.com/@RossWhitehouse/setting-up-eslint-in-react-c20015ef35f7) in your project. Or you could easily get tips from VSCode extension.